# installing 14.04 ubuntu alongside windows7

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows7.

I downloaded the .iso file and used linux live usb creater to boot from it, I tried it for sometime and it all works fine - but when I tried to install it at the installation type step where there is supposed to be partitions and stuff, there is only `/dev/sda` which is my ssd (not partitioned at all) and I dont want to use it.

I have another hdd 750 gb(/dev/sdb) that is partitioned into 4 partitions recovery , system , C (has my windows), E (empty, hopefully this where ubuntu goes)

Running `sudo fdisk -l`  shows 3 devices:

my ssd (/dev/sda)
Hdd (/dev/sdb)
And the sanddisk that i boot from (/dev/sdc)

If possible please tell me how to change "device for boot loader" from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb`

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot for sudo parted -l
http://postimg.org/image/qxm7viegj/

Comment: Would you please take a screenshot of this step you're talking about and post the image somewhere and give us the link here. Also I have an advice for you. Putting Ubuntu on the SSD will make it run much faster than putting it on the normal drive.

Comment: I am using my ssd to accelerate boot for my hdd which is so slow without it so i dont want to install it there and how do i screen shot on ubuntu?Edit: ok found it i will upload them shortly

Comment: okay but may I ask you how are you doing this? I mean how are you using it to accelerate booting?

Comment: Install intel rapid storage technology drivers and restart you will find the .exe in the start menu if not search for it .you will find the interface easy to use

Comment: hey this is where the bootloader will be. not ubuntu itself. you can carry on.

If you don't know what the bootloader is, it's "the thing" that starts ubuntu. It's not ubuntu itself.

Comment: ...about the intel drivers thing. I've never heard of it before but I really think putting windows on the SSD will make it work faster than using those drivers. And the same thing for ubuntu. It'd work faster on the SSD too

Comment: Ok then, how much space will it take so i can free that space? And should i add a partition there or just leave some space unallocated

Comment: few megabytes. no need to worry

Comment: uuuh no I think you just leave it as it is and continue

Comment: I tried to continue but it says " No root file system is defined Please correct this from partitioning menu

Comment: Can you boot into Live Mode and screenshot `sudo parted -l` and edit your question to include that screenshot? Also, I am unclear as to which disk you want to install Ubuntu onto.

Comment: I want to install it on /dev/sdb the hard drive

Comment: Can you temporarily unplug the SSD and then try it again?

Comment: Its built-in so i dont know how to do it and i have an ideapad which is really hard to open it up